# Saving Json/Dict responses to dataframe - they get converted to string on export. How to avoid this?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am running an API and saving the responses as a dictionary with `response.to_dict()` to a new column for referencing later.

Sample dataframe:

```
dict1 = {'thing': 200,
         'other thing': 18,
         'available_data': {'premium': {'emails': 1}},
         'query': {'names': [{'first': 'John','last': 'Smith'}]}}

dict2 = {'thing': 123,
         'other thing': 13,
         'available_data': {'premium': {'emails': 1}},
         'query': {'names': [{'first': 'Foo','last': 'Bar'}]}}


dict_frame = pd.DataFrame({'customers':['John','Foo'],
                           'api_response':[dict1,dict2]})

print(dict_frame)

  customers                                       api_response
0      John  {'thing': 200, 'other thing': 18, 'available_d...
1       Foo  {'thing': 123, 'other thing': 13, 'available_d...
```

We can see that the data is stil a `dict` type:

```
type(dict_frame.loc[1,'api_response'])

dict
```

However if I save it to file and re-load it, the data is now a string.

```
# save to file
dict_frame.to_csv('mydicts.csv')

# reload dataframe
dict_frame = pd.read_csv('mydicts.csv')

# check type
type(dict_frame.loc[1,'api_response'])

#it's a string
str
```

With some googling, I see there is a package to convert it back to a dict:

```
from ast import literal_eval

python_dict = literal_eval(first_dict)
```

It works, but I have a feeling there's a way to avoid this in the first place. Any advice?

I tried `dtype={'api_response': dict}` while reading in the csv, but `TypeError: dtype '<class 'dict'>' not understood`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a limitation of CSV file type: everything is converted to text. pandas must guess the data type when it reads the text back in. You can specify a converter:

```
from ast import literal_eval
dict_frame_csv = pd.read_csv('mydicts.csv', converters={'api_response': literal_eval})
```

Comment: OK, thanks. So as long as I don't save it to file and reload it, the data will stay as type dictionary in the dataframe?

Comment: That is correct is. CSV is a plain-text file type. If you want to maintain the type info use `to_pickle` / `read_pickle` or a suitable format from [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/frame.html#serialization-io-conversion)